# How to avoid reload solr plugin when solr index reloads during replication?

Tags: java, solr

Whenever Solr reloads index, it reloads my custom plugin which internally has some cached objects. How can I avoid reloads of my custom plugin?

Comment: I am not sure you can do that and probably you don't really want to do that as painful as it might sound. This is the documentation for [Solr RELOAD](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/coreadmin-api.html#CoreAdminAPI-RELOAD). In there it states that "_while the new core is initializing, the existing one will continue to handle requests. When the new Solr core is ready, it takes over and the old core is unloaded._"

Comment: Solr keeps reloading my caches within my custom plugin. It creates some instability. I am in searching for a way to not reload my custom plugin. In the documentation, it says "RELOAD performs "live" reloads of SolrCore, reusing some existing objects." Is it possible to instruct solr to make my plugin be part of the reusable existing objects?

Comment: I don't know, but sound kind of like that. I haven't dealt with Solr for some time; maybe 2.5 - 3 years. I remember being kind of hard to figure out at first. Took me a while to do what I wanted with it and then I had no problems. But, I used it in a very limited capacity.